# is there any way to support "expand" behavior in a standard web api 2 controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Is there any way to support "expand" behavior in a standard Web API 2 controller? I think that "expand" behavior is supported via OData controllers but I think this requires url requests in an OData format.  So to maybe simplify this problem further, let's say that I'm looking for a way to programatically build the response object based on an "expand" condition.  Here's an example of building a user-groups sub-collection to subsequently set to a Groups property on a User object:

```
private List<Group> GetUserGroups(Guid userId, List<Group> groups, List<Core.Models.GroupExtensionUserExtension> geueList, bool? expand)
{
    var userGroupIds = geueList.Where(x => x.UserExtensionId == userId).Select(x => x.GroupExtensionId);
    if (expand == null || expand == false) return userGroupIds.Select(x => new Group { Id = x }).ToList();
    else return groups.Where(x => userGroupIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
}
```

However, when I call GetUser using this approach, all Group property names are returned with null values, although I just want Groups returned with a populated Id property.  Is there anything that I can do to implement the design I have in mind in a standard Web API 2 controller?

Comment: I don't really see what this has to do with WebAPI. It seems to be more about your data store and how you're projecting your data before you return it in your `GetUser()` call, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @john - does "expand" functionality typically provide a way to return the id's of child objects instead of the full child objects?  or does "expand" typically only provide all-or-nothing expansion?  for example, it will return the full representation of User.Groups object or no User.Groups objects at all?

Comment: Referring to Microsoft's [ODATA docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value) it seems that it just wouldn't include the objects at all. Also, if you're seeing null properties, you should be able to configure that at the serializer level.